# Data structure for a static set of sets

Tags: data-structures, sets

I have collection $U$ of sets, where each set is of size at most 95 (corresponding to each printable ASCII character). For example, $\{h,r,l,a\}$ is one set, and $U = \{\{h,r,l,a\}, \{l,e,d\}, \ldots\}$. The number of sets in $U$ is nearly a million. Also a set in $U$ will mostly contains 8-20 elements.

I am looking for a datastructure for storing collection of sets that support following operations:

1. set matching,            e.g. check if set $\{h,r,l,a\}$ is present in $U$
2. subset matching          e.g. check if set $\{h,r,l\}$ is subset of any set in $U$
3. superset matching        e.g. check if set $\{h,r,l,a,s\}$ is superset of any set in $U$
4. union matching           e.g. check if set $\{h,r,l,a,e,d\}$ is union of sets in $U$
5. approximate set matching e.g. check if set $\{h,r,l,e\}$ is present in $U$, should return true

In particular, we can assume that once the data structure is built, no modifications are made but only queries of the above type (the structure is static).

I was thinking of trie data structure. But, it demands storing data in some order. So I have to store every set as a bit vector, but then the trie becomes binary decision tree. Am I in the right direction? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: The trivial solution would be to compare the input set with every set in U. I am looking for a more efficient solution. The number of sets in U is over a million.

Comment: So, with bitvector representation, I have to compare my input against every set in U?

Comment: Which operations need to be sublinear? I don't think you can have all operations sublinear. So a set contains maximal 4 elements? and approximate set matching is when a it only differs by one element? and in your sets the position of the elements is not important?

Comment: But the question talks about searching subset, superset in collection U. Most of the data structures related to set talk about searching an element in a set.

Comment: Can we talk about at least subset and superset operations?

Comment: @Curious [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201003/data-structure-for-querying-whether-a-given-subset-exists-in-a-collection-of-set) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542920/fastest-way-to-perform-subset-test-operation-on-a-large-collection-of-sets-with?lq=1); if it is static, you have memory, and want all operatiosn be sublinear, then build a seperate structure for each operation, this is imo the only way to achieve sublinearty for all operations.

Comment: In the future, when you cross-post, please link back to the other versions of the question http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/30655/8067 "datastructure for collection of sets" http://stackoverflow.com/q/28802695 "Data structure for approximate set matching"

Comment: What is the underlying problem? This smells like maybe there's a better solution if you start over.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generically, these are sometimes called [subset/containment dictionaries](https://books.google.com/books?id=3k5MVjKzBP4C&pg=PA138). The fact that you had partial matching in your question (but deleted it) is actually not a coincidence, because subset/containment queries and partial matching are equivalent problems for sets.

You probably want to use an [UBTree (unlimited branching tree)](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/unlimitedBranchingTree.html) for this; it's basically a modified trie. See [Hoffmann and Koehler (1998)](http://user.enterpriselab.ch/~takoehle/publications/ipp/publi/tr-108.pdf) for more details.

You could also have a look at the more recent *set-trie* data structure [proposed by Savnik (2013)](http://osebje.famnit.upr.si/~savnik/papers/cdares13.pdf) for the same purpose. (If you miss the color in the graphs in that preprint paper and don't have access to the [official Springer publication](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-40511-2_10) [in which the colors aren't missing], there's [precursor to that paper](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-924/paper06.pdf) which has almost the same graphs/info and no missing colors.)

Both papers (Hoffmann & Koehler, and respectively Savnik) have experimental results, so you can have some idea what they can handle in practice. Both seem to handle data sets with a cardinality of U around 1M.

If you somehow have [TCAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-addressable_memory#Ternary_CAMs) hardware (or the money for it), there's a way to [leverage that for subset/superset queries](http://web.stanford.edu/~ashishg/papers/inverted.pdf). You can actually do both subset/superset queries in parallel assuming you have enough TCAM words (2x |U|). 
Since TCAM words can be configured to be 144-bit wide, you and you have only 95 bits/letters to test, you wouldn't even need to bother with Bloom/hashing, you'd have an exact test using TCAM; this is trivial enough I'll even say here how: every {0, 1} bit-vector corresponding to every set in your U is simply turned into a {0, *} vector for subset queries and to a {1, *} vector for superset queries.

A more general problem tackled in [ETI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s11704-012-1237-5) (no free copy, sorry) is finding a set with given similarity measure. For example, the similarity measure can be $J(Q,S)=\frac{|Q\cap S|}{{|Q\cup S|}}$ and the query for a given $Q$ can be to find all $S$ (in the database) with $J(Q,S)\geq 0.3$. Both the constant and the similarity measure are user-definable as a predicate in ETI. (The $J$ given as example here is called the [Jaccard index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index).)

Comment: I was also thinking of modifying trie data structure for set operations. The paper by Savnik provided me the right direction. Also the more general similarity measure is [Tversy index("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tversky_index")]. Jaccard index and Dice's coeff are just special cases of Tversky index.